# qt progress bar is not working properly

Tags: php, c++, qt, post, qtnetwork

I have one problem..
I am making post request to php script. And I am getting back result as an xml. How can I make my qprogressbar working.
I have tried this:
v

```
oid MainWindow::init()
{
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/direkt_php_qt.php";
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(updateDataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void MainWindow::updateDataTransferProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(bytesTotal + (bytesTotal * 0.25));
    ui->progressBar->setValue(bytesReceived);
    ui->progressBar->show();
}
```

But it's not working. I am getting error:
`Object::connect: No such signal QNetworkAccessManager::downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)`

How can I make this work with manager variable or something like that.

EDIT 2:
This is for example function that is calling init()

```
void MainWindow::Citanje_korisnika()
{
    init();

    QUrl params;
        params.addQueryItem("action","Citanje_korisnika");

        QByteArray data;
        data.append(params.toString());
        data.remove(0,1);

        QNetworkRequest request;
        request.setUrl(url);
        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
        QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        reply = manager->post(request, data);

}
```

I tried your code but I always get unexpectedly out from program. Can you change me my function from which I am calling post method so it can work with init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

donwloadProgress is a signal of [QNetworkReply](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html).
Try something like this:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/direkt_php_qt.php";
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),this, SLOT(updateDataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)));
```

Comment: anyone maybe knows the answer?

Comment: Okay I made it work. How to make it go smoothly and not like jumping from 24% to 100% in a sec.